# contine with page if "if" not the variable

Tags: javascript, mobile, if-statement, responsive-design

I am creating a responsive design of my website for smartphones based on browser width...

this code i got somewhere on this site.... Thank you whomever u r.

```
function viewPort() {

var h = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

var w = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;

}
```

which runs great so I followed with:

```
if ( viewPort().width <= 600) {

      window.location.href = "ams/1.cfm?W=" + viewPort().width + ""
}

else {

}
```

so the regular page would continue to load if the browser > 600

the first part works fine but when the browser exceeds 600 the page stops loading and does nothing... tried without else tag first.

also should I have some sort of "abort" if the if statement is true?

Comment: The *viewPort* function doesn't return anything.

Comment: add whole of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your viewPort function dosent return anything

```
function viewPort() {
        var h = window.innerHeight 
               || document.documentElement.clientHeight 
               || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;
        var w = window.innerWidth 
                || document.documentElement.clientWidth 
                || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;

        return {width : w, height : h};
        }

        var size = viewPort();
        if ( size.width <= 600) {

          window.location.href = "ams/1.cfm?W=" + size.width + "";
        }
```

Comment: sorry i left 

return { width : w , height : h }
}

out in my post... and if i point to another url in the else statement it goes there. i just can't seem to get the rest of the page to load if the "if" is not true...

Comment: got that working fine but rather than send to another page i am trying to send via a form tag... 

<form action="5.cfm" method="POST" target="_self">
 
<input type="text" name="cats"> <input type="hidden" name="example" id="example"> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("example").setAttribute('value',' + size.width + '); 
</script> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> </form> 

the "example" field doesn't even show in the target page (self) after submit

Answer (score 0):

Your viewPort function doesn't return a value. It is essentially a no-op. It declares two local variables, but those variables are not accessible by the rest of the script. To return a value, use a single return statement at the end of the function body.

You probably want to delete the height calculation since you're not using it, and return the result of the width calculation ("return w;"). Then you should rename the function to something appropriate like "getViewportWidth".

Additionally, when you call this function, you attempt to access a property called "width" on its return value. This will result in an error, causing your page to malfunction. Once your function is simply returning the viewport width, you can remove this property references so that you're just comparing the returned value with 600 ("getViewportWidth() >= 600").

Answer (score 0):

Tnx Robert.

Can't seem to get the variables into a format that i can pass along as CF variables. Also I am using both height and width to set up the smartphone browser interface and use 3 different sized images based on those dimensions so i don't have to resize images and pixalate.

Maybe impossible but would like to get rid of variables in path by doing a cfinclude instead of the statement"

```
window.location.href = "ams/1.cfm?W=" + size.width + "";
```

Something like this...

```
CFIF ISDefined('width') 

cfset width =  

cfset height = 

cfinclude template="2.cfm"

cfabort

/cfif
```

Tnx Andy